# URL file-access is disabled in the server

Tags: php, wordpress

URL file-access is disabled in the server - is the error I'm getting with Short URLs.  I'm no PHP coder, so if you could post the code I should be using I would appreciate it!  **How do I rewrite the path?**

In functions:

```
//////////////////////////////////////// Custom templates: page templates
add_filter('single_template', create_function('$t', 'foreach( (array) get_the_category() as $cat ) { if ( file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH . "/single-{$cat->term_id}.php") ) return TEMPLATEPATH . "/single-{$cat->term_id}.php"; } return $t;' ));
```

The call:

```
<?php $turl = getTinyUrl(get_permalink($post->ID));
echo 'Short URL <a href="'.$turl.'">'.$turl.'</a>' ?>
```

Comment: Googling the error message is often a useful first step

Comment: The warning says it all. You need to enable URL file access in `php.ini` to be able to use `file_get_contents` on a remote file.

Comment: There is a way to fix this with paths, I just don't know how.

Comment: ////////////////////////////////// cool comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If PHP has [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) enabled you can add this function:

```
function getTinyUrl2($url) {
  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //Set curl to return the data instead of printing it to the browser.
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=".$url);

  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  return $data;
}
```

and then change your code to use the new function:

```
$turl = getTinyUrl2(get_permalink($post->ID));
echo 'Tiny Url for this post: <a href="'.$turl.'">'.$turl.'</a>'
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score -1):

Tinyurl.com does not allow you to get file by php's file_get_contents function.
Use curl instead to use tinyurl api.

```
<?php
   $url = "http://example.com";
   $ch = curl_init("http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=".$url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFERT, true);
   $tinyurl = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: Of course, it does allow you. The warning has nothing to do with TinyURL. :)

Comment: The cURL alternative is correct, but to say that Tinyurl.com has any idea what function in what programming language it's URLs are called from is way off. The problem in this case is server configuration, you  need this line in php.ini: `allow_url_fopen = On`

Comment: Exact, I read too fast.
As they say, modify php.ini ... Or put `ini_set ("allow_url_fopen" , "on");` in your script.